# TypeScript: Annotate `is string` instead of `boolean`?

Tags: typescript

It seems to me that TypeScript interprets `typeof x === 'string'` not only as a simple boolean, but as some kind of a boolean `is string` type.

Consider this example:

```js
const tryInference = function(maybeStr?: string): void {

  const isStrI          = typeof maybeStr === 'string'; // inferred type "is string"
  const isStrB: boolean = typeof maybeStr === 'string'; // explicit boolean

  console.log( isStrI && maybeStr.charAt(0) ); // <-- ok
  console.log( isStrB && maybeStr.charAt(0) ); // <-- TS18048: 'maybeStr' is possibly 'undefined'.

  const indeedStr1: string = isStrI ? maybeStr : ''; // <-- ok
  const indeedStr2: string = isStrB ? maybeStr : ''; // <-- TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

  console.log( indeedStr1, indeedStr2 );
};
```

I understand that in case of `isStrI` TypeScript knows that if `typeof maybeStr === 'string'` then `maybeStr.charAt` is available.

I suppose that in case of `isStrB && maybeStr.charAt(0)` TypeScript interprets it as `true && maybeStr.charAt(0)`, and doesn't have the relation to the `typeof maybeStr === 'string'` anymore ? *(if isStrB is true, of course)*

That makes me wonder:

1. Can I annotate `isStrI` explicitly somehow, without destroying the information that `maybeStr` is of type `string` ?
2. Am I right with my assumptions ? Does somebody have a more detailed explaination ?

Comment: In the typescript playground `isStrI` inferred type is boolean?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Yes, the inferred type of `isStrI` is shown as `boolean`. So both, `isStrB` and `isStrI` are `boolean`. The difference is only when they are used later.

Comment: There are a few answers on this here on the site, I don't have a link to hand. Short version is, as @kelsny said, no, TypeScript can't remember that variable A being true means variable B has a narrower type. It can do *flow* analysis, but not that kind of correlation between things not in the same structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently possible.

The support for [control flow analysis of aliased conditions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#44730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730) doesn't occur at the type level in a way you can manipulate programmatically.  The type of the variable is just `boolean` either way; no type annotation could capture its relationship to `maybeStr` ([type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) do not exist as standalone types).  And furthermore, annotating the variable destroys the relationship:

> Narrowing through indirect references occurs only when the conditional expression or discriminant property access is declared in a `const` variable declaration **with no type annotation** [emphasis added], and the reference being narrowed is a `const` variable, a `readonly` property, or a parameter for which there are no assignments in the function body.